# Fetch only the ids from a hasMany in Grails?

Tags: grails

I know I can do `Parent.childId` in Grails, but is there anything similar I can do to only load ids (proxies) for every children in a hasMany? I.e., something similar to `Parent.childrenIds`?

In my case, the hasMany is mapped by a joinTable.

Comment: Not as elegant, but I'm sure a `createCriteria()` solution is possible.  Thinking about how the db tables are mapped out with the child class having the parent's id in a column, probably results in a fetch regardless, so I'm not sure how much you can gain.

Comment: Actually, I'm using a joinTable for this particular relationship - so the children ids are available in a separate table. If Grails offered a Parent.childrenIds or similar that detail would probably be handled behind the curtains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `joinTable` in mind:

```
def getChildIds(parentId) {
    Child.withSession { session -> 
        def sql = new Sql(session.connection())    
        sql.rows(
            'select pc.child_id from parent_child pc where pc.parent_id = :parentId',
             [parentId: parentId]
        ).collect{ it.child_id }
    }
}
```

This works for a `joinTable` mapped as such:

```
class Parent {

    static mapping = {
        childs joinTable: [name: 'parent_child', column: 'child_id', key: 'parent_id']
    }
    ...
```

It's not pretty but I believe it's the best way considering the situation and requirement.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as an answer, though I'm not going to use it due to the "not pretty"-part :-) Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a [projection](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.9/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html). e.g.

```
def result = Child.createCriteria().list {
    projections {
        property('id')
    }
    eq ('parent', parent)
}
```

This will return just the ids of the child objects.

Comment: Thanks & good answer. But I'm using a joinTable for this particular relationship, so I'm afraid this won't solve it out-of-the-box (parent is not available in the child domain). Sorry for leaving that out, I didn't realize it until you answered.

Answer (score 0):

I used "Querying Associations" and "Projection" to do this in the Parent domain object. ([Query - GORM for Hibernate](https://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#criteria)):

```
class Parent {

    static hasMany = [childs: Child]
    static mapping = {
        childs joinTable: [name: 'parent_child', key: 'parent_id', column: 'child_id']
    }

    Collection<Long> getChildIds(){
        withCriteria {
            childs {
                projections {
                    property 'id'
                }
            }
            eq 'id', id
        }
    }

}
```